# Webview returns blank white page in electron js

Tags: html, electron

I am using the boiler plate electron js quick start and trying to render a webview from their  API docs. Heres my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hello World!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <webview id="foo" src="https://www.github.com/" style="display:inline-flex; width:640px; height:480px"></webview></webview>
  </body>
</html>
```

It just renders a blank screen. I tried on Ubuntu and OSX. There are no errors in the console. I'm not even sure where to start debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1280,
    height: 1080,
    webPreferences: {
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
      webviewTag: true
    },
  })
```

You have to enable webviewTag inside webPreferences when making your browser window.